# How do I connect a PCIe x4 NVMe 1.4 M.2-SSD to a USB-A Port?

Tags: usb, ssd, adapter

I've got a [Corsair MP600 PRO XT](https://www.digitec.ch/en/s1/product/corsair-mp600-pro-xt-1000-gb-m2-2280-ssd-16599916). This SSD has some Ransomware on it that probably encrypted the whole disk, even the OS Folders and files, so when I start my Computer I basically can't do anything I only see a blinking Taskbar.

I'd like to connect it to a laptop via USB to see if I can somehow get some Logfiles.

Comment: Ransomware tries to 'sell' you something and will 'advertise' what it did and your ticket out. Just crippling a drive does not sound like a good way to sell you something so I doubt this is ransomware. A failed SSD is far more likely.

Comment: @JoepvanSteen it is a ransomware but a pretty dumb one :). Me and the security guy found it funny as well

Comment: Okay. You happen to know which ransomware?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just search for "M.2 NVME SATA SSD Enclosure".

Random [example](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08C2THR25).